# How to use the boxscorematchups endpoint for nba_api?

Tags: python, json, nba-api

I imported the package as such:

`from nba_api.stats.endpoints import boxscorematchups`

No issues there. But when I try to run this code:

```
match = boxscorematchups.BoxScoreMatchups(game_id='0022200771')
```

I get the following error:

`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

I've read through the documentation [here](https://github.com/swar/nba_api/blob/master/docs/nba_api/stats/endpoints/boxscorematchups.md) a bunch of times, and I have everything right as far as I can tell. 'game_id' is supposed to be the only parameter, so I don't understand what the error is about. I'm stuck.

I've tried the same game_id with different nba_api endpoints I've used before, and it's worked fine. For instance this code runs fine:

`match0 = boxscoretraditionalv2.BoxScoreTraditionalV2(game_id='0022200771')`

I don't know what's different about the boxscorematchups endpoint to cause this error.